# Deleting memory allocated with pointers (dynamic array)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management, allocation

If I create 2 pointers:

```
int *pointer;
int *temp;
```

and I allocate memory for one of them in this case `temp`:

```
temp = new int [ size ]; //size = 6
```

I then point my second pointer `pointer` to the same memory location:

```
pointer = temp;
```

If I want to deallocate temp:

```
delete [ ] temp;
```

it won’t let me… And I say it won’t let me because if I do a loop to populate elements of `temp` it will still let me populate it even after I used `delete [ ] temp;`. I am trying to understand what happens here so now my questions are:

1. When I did `delete [ ] temp;` was the memory deallocated (I think not because I had another pointer pointing to that location) and if it wasn’t… does that means the `delete [ ] temp;` had no effect?
2. Is it possible to deallocate memory if more than one pointer is pointing to that memory location?
3. Lets say that i am done with both pointers and I want to free the memory, what would be the best way to do it? I cannot do `delete [ ] pointers;` because I never allocated memory for pointer I just pointed it to the `temp` memory address.

Note: I know that I can use vectors I am just trying to understand memory management while using pointers.

Comment: I don't get an error, program compiles and works fine, I say it won't let me because even after I did delete [ ] temp; I still can get access to that memory location.

Comment: Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E (and read some books)

Comment: Raw arrays in C++ are not "dynamic" (they do not dynamically grow or shrink), but can be *dynamically allocated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > When I did `delete [ ] temp;` was the memory deallocated

   Yes it was. Using the memory after deletion causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), i.e. anything can happen, including but not limited to: code compiles, code crashes, code runs as expected, …

   > if i do a loop to populate elements of `temp` I will still let me populate it even after I used `delete [ ] temp;`

   C++ has no mechanism to prevent use-after-delete. If you're doing that then you're simply invoking undefined behavior.
2. > Is it possible to deallocate memory if more than one pointer is pointing to that memory location?

   Yes. Again, there's nothing in C++ that's going to stop the programmer from doing this. You have to make sure your code is not double-deleting anything or accessing anything that has already been deallocated.
3. > I cannot do `delete [ ] pointers;` because I never allocated memory for pointer I just pointed it to the temp memory address.

   You *can* delete the memory via `pointer` too. Any pointer that points to the allocated memory **and has the same type that was used to allocate the memory** can be used to delete it.

   Finally, do as dasblinkenlight said: avoid advanced manual memory handling like `new` and `delete`, and prefer **smart pointers** instead. They will automagically deallocate your memory 1) at the right time, and 2) only once. After that they reset themselves to `nullptr` making use-after-delete easy to spot.

Comment: If by "no mechanism" you mean "it ships with a standard library that can trivially handle it" then yes.

Comment: @Puppy Smart pointers don't prevent use-after-delete afaik, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

> When I did `delete [ ] temp;` was the memory deallocated

Of course it was! `delete` operator is very obedient, it assumes that if you ask it to delete a chunk of memory, then you are done with that chunk for good.

> I think not because I had another pointer pointing to that location

The moment you called `delete []` on the `temp` that other pointer became *dangling*. Dereferencing it is [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/335858), meaning that your program is invalid, even though it compiles or even runs to completion without a crash.

> Is it possible to deallocate memory if more than one pointer is pointing to that memory location?

Yes, that is, in fact, what happens.

> Lets say that i am done with both pointers and i want to free the memory, what would be the best way to do it?

Use smart pointers, e.g. [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). This would let you avoid calling `delete` altogether.